# Because project depends on wakelock 0.5.6 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed

Tags: flutter

I just downloaded the source code of an app online made on Flutter
Unzipped the folder, Opened in Android studio
I run Flutter pub get

- flutter upgrade and pub upgrade and pub outdated

Im getting below Error

**Running "flutter pub get" in Project...

Because project depends on wakelock 0.5.6 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because project depends on wakelock 0.5.6 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1**

Comment: this is bcs in your pubsec.yaml file their are some dependecy conflicts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue by following the below steps in my case

1. Delete pubspec.lock file (Which is generated by flutter pub get previously)
2. Flutter clean
3. pubspec.yaml file >
   added `wakelock: any` instead of `wakelock: 0.5.6`
4. then run `flutter pub upgrade`
5. last `flutter pub get`
   finally, Run the build

Comment: this is not a good practice, especially for production, it is better to specify the latest compatible version instead of `any`.

Answer (score 7):

to fix this problem, I changed my "pubspec.yaml" like this:
for the version of packages, change to the latest version or just write "any" instead without quotes

```
dependencies:
  ...
  wakelock: ^0.6.2
  wakelock_windows: ^0.2.1

dependency_overrides:
  ...
  win32: ^5.0.0
```

Comment: By using latest versions from pub.dev there are issues in many dependencies. I just remove versions from the mentioned dependencies and the problem Solved.
thanks!